# Rails4; scope returns ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation not single object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just wonder how I can return one object instead of `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` within models with `scope`.

For example,

```
scope :primary, -> { where(is_active: true).last }
```

which returns `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`.

So I always have to something like `Account.last.credit_cards.primary.last`.

How can I achieve this more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code already returns a single object. It's a good practice to return `ActiveRecord_Relation` instead: in this case, you can write like

```
YourObject.scope_1(params).scope_2.where(...)
```

Using `limit` instead of `last` returns `ActiveRecord_Relation`:

```
scope :primary, -> { where(is_active: true).limit(1) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried but returns empty array '[]' .

Comment: It means empty scope.

Comment: `last` returns ActiveRecord object, not a scope.